# Spring - set of properties files to list of beans

Tags: spring, mule

I have a list of properties files that contains the same set of keys, for example:

```
database1.properties
databaseName=xxx
databasePassword=yyy

database2.properties
databaseName=zzzz
databasePassword=kkkk
```

Using Spring, how can I manage to store the two properties file in a list of 2 beans?
The beans will have two attributes, databaseName and databasePassword.
This will be used on a mule flow.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Try something like the following.

```
<bean id="properties1" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
   <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true"/>
   <property name="placeholderPrefix" value="${database1."/>
   <property name="locations">
    <list>
      <value>classpath:database1.properties</value>
    </list>
  </property>
</bean>

<bean id="properties2" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
   <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="false"/>
   <property name="placeholderPrefix" value="${database2."/>
   <property name="locations">
    <list>
      <value>classpath:database2.properties</value>
    </list>
  </property>
</bean>
```

And you can refer to the properties at your beans as  **database1.databaseName**      or  **database2.databaseName**

Hope this helps.